# double insert-select statement in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to move data from one table into two tables.

for example

I have `TableA` with `A,B,C,D,E` fields (this is the old table), and `TableX` and `TableY`. `TableX` contains `A`,`B` and `C` fields and `TableY` contains `D` and `E`.

Currently I have a query that inserts the data into the first table but not in the second, something like

```
INSERT INTO TableX
(A,B,C)
SELECT A,B,C 
FROM TableA
```

This works

The 3 tables contains their id's and in the new structure `TableY` must contain a reference with `TableX`, the complete fields of table would

complete fields of table would

```
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_toX` int(10) not NULL,
  `D` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `E` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
```

How insert the the reference of `TableX` in `TableY` of the same record of the `TableA`???

Answer (score 1):

Alter `TableA` to contain a unique ID which you can insert into both of the new tables. Use this column to create whatever references you wish, then remove this column if it is no longer needed with another `ALTER TABLE`.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
INSERT INTO TableY (id_toX, D, E)
SELECT DISTINCT t2.id, t1.D, t1.E
FROM TableA as t1
inner join
TableX as t2
on (t1.A=t2.A and t1.B=t2.B and t1.C=t2.C)
```

Comment: @doublesharp yes, it is better to have a+b+c unique in this case

Comment: This is a fast solution, great in this scenario, but in my case `(t1.A=t2.A and t1.B=t2.B and t1.C=t2.C)` is no a unique :(

Comment: @jasilva then make them unique, as there is no sense in storing absolutely the same values/rows with only distinct IDs